# Помогите в чем тут ошибка. Если запускать из main все работает, пытаюсь в function.cpp засунуть не работает

Tags: c++, массивы

> 83|error: 'srand' was not declared in this scope
>   91|error: 'rand' was not declared in this scope

```
void prim2(){

srand((int) time(0));
int N;
cout <<"N="; cin >>N;

double*a = new double[N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
  a[i]=rand()%9 + 1;
  cout <<a[i]<<" ";
  }
cout <<endl;

for (int i=N-1; i>0; i--)
a[i]=a[i-1];

a[0]=0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  cout <<a[i]<<" ";

delete[]a;
```

Comment: Пробовали перевести ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

надо было подключить `#include <ctime>
                        #include <cstdlib>`